# Can i Create Custom Button same like Create PDF button of Quotes?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, metadata, custom-metadata

when i click on **Create Pdf** then this pdf Preview open,i need exactly same functionality .
[image]

```
i want to create button like  Create PDF button of Quotes, i make same functionality for my custom object , How can i make it ?
```

add image below like that i want to make.
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more on where you want to add the button and what will be the functionality?

Comment: Do you also need the little PDF Preview thing with the email options and all that or do you just need to create a pdf from your object fields? You can easily make a button to just create a pdf of the object fields if you don't need the other stuff.

Comment: i will add one more image so you can understand when i click on Create Pdf then this pdf Preview open ,i want to add button on my custom object ,i need exactly same functionality  as you can see in image but it's standard so how can i make like that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a button that execute JavaScript. Your JavaScript should use `"/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js"`

Have a look on this [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097vaIAA) for sample code